# Why are MIOTA transferred to the same wallet and then do not appear anymore?

Tags: transaction, wallet, tangle, address

I sent 999 MIOTA to my wallet, but after they were received they were immediately transferred again to the same wallet and now the wallet is empty. Can you please explain me what happened and where my MIOTA are now?

https://thetangle.org/address/CISHLVHMVJPWJYRMZJPAHVVLUSKRPHMHYAFYPBYESBVIYCRBPYFHPCPOHZWHK9ISBWDDRMUYFKCEZR9PD

Comment: Is this your own wallet running on your own machine (if yes, how did you generate your seed?), or is it an online wallet of an exchange?